# Fitness: Different Exceptions Fitnesseoutput vs. Console

Tags: java, testing, fitnesse

I wrote a simple Fitnesse tes which works fine. Today I found that there is a difference in the error which shown by the fitnesse generated output page (NoSuchElementException) and the output shown by the console (java.lang.Exception). Any idea what causes this and how can I make sure the correct error is shown by the console as well?

The situation is like this.

In my content file I have a line like:

```
 |check|field exists|testknop|true|
```

The corresponding method in my fixture looks like:

```
public boolean fieldExists(String fieldName) {
    // Als het element niet gevonden kan worden treed eer een exception op dus assert is niet
    // nodig
    driver.findElement(By.id(fieldName));
    // sluit driver weer af
    driver.quit();
    return false;
}
```

Now the generated fitnesse report the line is marked yellow, containing a stacktrace with a selenium NoSuchElementException.

When I run it from maven I get a generic java.lang.Exception

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more details: what does your test looks like, what error you get and how you run from console?

Comment: I've found a solution, See the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that works for me.

The porblem was that the `driver.findElement(By.id(fieldName));` causes an exception sometimes.

When I change the test and code as I posted below it works for mee.

```
|check|field exists|testknop|inloggen gelukt|


public String fieldExists(String fieldName) {
    // Als het element niet gevonden kan worden treed eer een exception op dus assert is niet
    // nodig
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id(fieldName));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "Inloggen mislukt";
    }
    // sluit driver weer af
    driver.quit();
    return "inloggen gelukt";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run with junit runner (what I expect you do from maven) you don't get detailed info from your tests on the console. Like you encountered here.

What I do is check the generated html report to see what really happened and only rely on the console to detect at least one test did not pass (so I know that I should investigate).

Comment: when I run it with maven as I stated above, Ik het something like:
Test.LoginTest failed: [inloggen mislukt]  expected [inloggen gelukt].
don't know the exact message as i dont have the code with me now.

But yes, jenkins should display the generated html report. But at least the console output is not cunfusing anymore doing it this way.